# CSVPrinter is appending \ to the long string while generating csv

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to generate a csv using CSVPrinter. The csv generation is working fine. But for some cases i am getting '' in front of a string and for the same reason the next part of the string is shifting to the next cell.

```
try {
    csvPrinter.printRecord(
        separationModel.getDate(),
        separationModel.getHours(),
        separationModel.getStatement(),
        separationModel.getNotes(),
        separationModel.getRehire(),
        separationModel.getComments().trim().replace("\\", ""), //trying to replace the \ from the string here
```

For this i am getting one value in one cell like

```
i am here\
the next part in the next cell
```

But actually the value should be in one cell

```
 i am here the next part in the next cell
```

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you show as the real string of the getComments() value

Comment: @MaroineMlis see i have pasted  a screeen shot from the code

Comment: put it as a text please, it will be simple to copy and past it, but i think the only reason about your problem as that your getComments() could have a back line character

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: @OlafKock "He came for his initial day of training on the iPad\" -> this is the sample text

Comment: @Mandrek there's an "edit" button below your question - and the reason for editing is in the article I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your comments in the separationModel contains a string with a back line (\n).

So try to add an other replace for \n

```
    String comments = "i am here\\\nthe next part in the next cell ";
    System.out.println(comments);
    /*
    i am here\
    the next part in the next cell
     */
    comments = comments.trim().replace("\\","").replace("\n"," ");
    System.out.println(comments);
    /*
    i am here the next part in the next cell
     */
```